# Using the context of a Github Action, IM trying to get the context of the PR Owner

Tags: github, github-actions

I was trying to do something which has been done a million times I feel.   If someone comments on a PR i want a Github action to capture it and get both the commentor username and the PR Owner Username.

Src Docs:  https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

I was trying something like:

```yaml
name: pr-commented
run-name: PR Commented On
on: issue_comment
jobs:
  pr-comment:
    name: PR Comment Detected
    if: ${{ github.event.issue.pull_request }}
    runs-on: ubuntu:latest
    steps:
    - name: Determine PR Owner and Commentor
      run: |
        OWNER=${{  }} # Im not sure what goes in these blocks
        COMMENTER=${{ github.actor }} # I think the actor in this case would be the Individual who comments.
    - name: Process Data
      run: |
        echo $OWNER, It seems $COMMENTER wants you.
```

I feel I am close, but I feel i am just missing something.

Comment: You can always dump an object to inspect it with something like `echo ${{ toJson(github.actor) }}`, or (better) set it in the environment and then print, see [the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#example-printing-context-information-to-the-log).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just retrieve it by using

```
github.event.issue_comment.user.login
```

Comment: is this the person who added the comment, or the PR Owner though

Comment: It's the PR owner